# How can I know the number of the row that has specific conditions? In R

Tags: r, matrix, row

I have this dataframe:

```
d <- structure(list(a = c(1, 66, 58, 0, 91, 37), b = c(44, 0, 75, 
11, 0, 32), c = c(0, 81, 0, 53, 25, 13)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I need to know, for each column, the position (row number) of the first zero. In this case the result should be

```
4, 2, 1
```

How can I do? Thx for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `max.col`:

```r
max.col(t(d) == 0, "first")
```

---

If you only have positive values, you can also do:

```r
sapply(d, which.min)
# [1] 4 2 1
```

Comment: The `which.min` is not correct. What if we had negatives? The `max.col` is correct

Comment: Yes, I'm saying "if you only have positive values". This is not working otherwise.

Comment: One would think the statement carries over to the `max.col`. I guess you should consider switching the order of the answers. ie `max.col` first then the `sapply` one

Comment: Thanks! i.e. If a column doesn't have a zero, why every of these function return "1"?

Comment: Because it's returning the min or max.

Comment: If i need "if there isn't zero return 0 or NA" for example, how can i do?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
sapply(d, function(x) which(x==0)[1])
# a b c 
# 4 2 1
```

Comment: Thx for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```r
apply(d, 2, function(x) which.max(x == 0))

#> a b c 
#> 4 2 1
```